# How does Keras process data internally?

Tags: keras

Keras expects an array of a certain shape as an input. So far so good.
How does it treat this array in respect to an order? Will the first row be calculated the first and then one after another?
Or is it vice versa? Or abitrary? Is there any determined sequence?

[image: array]

LSTM-layers are probably something different and, exceptionally, easier to understand in this context.

Comment: I don't know the answer but I doubt it's safe to assume any order of calculations, because they can be done in parallel.

Comment: so when performing a CV one must not take into account randomization? :D

Comment: I don't see the relation between the order of calculations and  CV randomization?

Comment: you can shuffe the data when using CV in python which is recommended, e.g.: "StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=42)"

Comment: the background is I am using time series data so the order is highly important. I just wonder that when I pay extra attention to the CV to be suitable for time series aka when using TimeSeriesSplit() and then, when Keras mixes the data arbitrarily anyway..  then that wasn't meaningful.. :D

Comment: I don't know how times series are treated with NNs, but I would be careful about assuming that order is taken into account. You should probably add this info in the question, maybe somebody who has experience with it can answer. (or maybe ask a new question)